# Negative Ve Turning on n-Channel BJT

Tags: bjt

I've often seen a protective diode placed between the Base and Emitter of an n-channel BJT to prevent reverse voltage breakdown (see image attached).

My one question here is: if I have an AC Source connected to 'Ve," can the negative voltage produced accidentally cause the BJT to turn on? I'd like to use *isolated* GPIO pins between 2.5-5VDC for Vb and Vc, but am worried that even setting these to 'Digital Read' (Open Circuit, or floating) will cause the transistor to turn on if its Ve value swings to -177VAC.

The 2.5-5V signals would be triggered on when the BJT is **not** connected to an AC Source, and triggered to 'floating/digital READ' when the AC Source is connected to Ve.

Thanks for your help! Can provide more drawings if needed. If there's an issue with using this circuit with a BJT, I could always use an n-channel Power MOSFET instead.

[image]

Comment: Most small signal BJTs cannot tolerate more than about 5 V of reverse voltage across their base-emitter junction. They can usually stand off much more, 30 V and above, across their reverse-biased base-collector junction. I don't think I can easily parse your comments about whether or not this might happen without the added diode. But having a diode there can be helpful, at times, in protecting the BJT.

Comment: Your schematic seems incomplete, so we can only speculate. However a -177 volts at Ve would cause and unprotected bjt/Jfet/MOSFET to explode, depending if the supply current was limited to safe levels.

Comment: Voltage is a measurement between 2 points. Work out what the transistor's Vbe is and that will tell you if it's forward biased enough to turn on.

Comment: In this case I’m assuming the negative AC Voltage is applied to Ve when the BJT *is* protected. I know that a positive voltage applied to Ve will be fine, as the diode will provide a 0.7 reverse bias drop saving the Emitter-Base junction voltage from getting too large. My question really concerns applying a negative voltage to Ve, with the BJT protected, and Vc and Vb floating. (Floating, due to setting the GPIOs tied to these points to a Digital Read State)

Comment: I am a bit confused. You want to apply x amount of current or voltage to a BJT emitter but leave base and collector open? A whole lot of nothing should happen, or is this real vs.imaginary equations?

Comment: The above cct will never function with more than +/- 1V and needs a large resistor if you have any ideas fora large AC voltage